# How to use Kusto query with parameters on Expression builder in DataFlow activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Ì am trying to pass some parameters to the Kusto query that are inside a DataFlow activity which are inside a ForEach activity as well, but it's always complaining on the Expression Builder in the source of the DataFlow.

[image: Kusto example]

My pipeline:
[image]

My dataflow:
[image]

How can I use those parameters on expression builder in DataFlow activity to my Kusto query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When query is given in query text box by clicking **Add dynamic content**, there is error message in dataflow expression builder. Instead, you can use the below workaround to achieve the same requirement of filtering the table.

- Enter the query without where option in the query text box of source transformation. *Do not write the query in the expression builder by clicking add dynamic content. Write it directly on the text box or by clicking on the edit icon.*

```
let conversion= datatable (Decimal: int, hexcode: string, binary: string)
[
0,'0','0000',
15,'f','1111'
];
conversion
```

[image]

- Then take the filter transformation and give the filter on condition as `hexcode==$hexcode`.
- For data preview, $hexcode parameter is assigned with value "f". Only one row is displayed in the preview.
  [image]

Use the filter transformation and pass the parameter in that transformation instead of giving in the source query itself.

Comment: Thanks Aswin for the answer. But that query was just an example, I would like to  use the filters with parameters inside the query, because I may have a lot of different filters. Is there a way to use multiline query with the filter as parameter?

Comment: Multiline query in dynamic content is not working.

Comment: Either you can use the single line query or use the filter transformation. FIlter transformation supports multiple conditions simultaneously. Refer the [img](https://i.imgur.com/k4zZly4.png)